# Syntax for Specifying file path (relative and absolute)

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I want to know a way of specifying the path of files. I am currently following:

```
href="css/lib/bootstrap.css"
```

I find that some people specify the file location in a different way:

```
templateUrl: 'lib:components/bootstrap.css'
```

I am not able to understand how to create/specify custom directories, as mentioned above using `lib:` or `package:`.

A brief on creating custom packages in dart would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to reference a file from the `lib` directory and the path contains a package name you always omit the `lib` directory in the path. Paths containing the package name implicitly go into the `lib` directory.

I have never seen the `lib:xxx` import style you mentioned.

### import Dart files

That is different depending on context

- If you want to import a Dart library file to another Dart file:

  - relative

  `import '../otherdir/somefile.dart';`

You should use this only if you are referencing a file within the same top-level package directory
(between files and folders within the `lib` directory (or within `bin`, `web`, `test`, `example`)

- absolute

  `import 'package:somepackage/somedir/somefile.dart';`

(`somedir` is a subdirectory of of the `lib` directory in the package `somepackage`.
You can use such an absolute path even within the same package.
When you want to reference a file in the `lib` directory from a file in the `web` (or `bin`, `web`, ...) directory
it is preferred to use this absolute path variant.

```dart
`import 'package:mypackage/somedir/somefile.dart';`
```

### Import other resource files

This may differ between different frameworks (AngularDart, PolymerDart, ...)
You can also either reference using an relative path or an absolute path.

#### Polymer

In Polymer you need to use relative paths for all ressource files.

You need to go up to the top-level directory like `web` and then from there further using the `packages` directory.

If your file is in `web/somedir` and you want to reference a file in `lib/otherdir` you reference it

```dart
href='../packages/mypackage/otherdir/somefile.css
```

If you want further examples you should describe your concrete situation.

- what framework are you using
- where are the files (source/target)
- what is the purpose of the import (import a CSS to an entry page or to a Polymer element, or to a Angular component, ...)

If you want to import a file from another package and the file you import to is stored in the `lib` directory you need to go one extra level up (I think that is a temporary workaround and might change before Polymer 1.0 is released).

Example:

two files like

```dart
my_package1/lib/comp1/comp1.html
my_package2/lib/comp2/comp2.html
```

to import `comp1` from `comp2` you need

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/mypackage1/comp1/comp1.html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the eloborate answer Gunter. I saw such usage in 'https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app/blob/master/lib/components/agenda_component.dart', under the templateUrl. I still want to know, is there a certain folder structure we need to follow, to use `import 'package:mypackage/somedir/somefile.dart';`. Or a certain config, i am not able to get things working with this syntax.

Comment: The package URI only works for files inside the `lib` directory of a package (but you omit the `lib` part in the actual import path)

Comment: That is a custom implementation. He has some code that replaces URLs that start with `lib:` to URLs that start with `packages` https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app/blob/master/lib/talk_to_me.dart

Comment: In HTML there is not `package:` but hrefs containing `packages/` can also only refer to files inside the `lib` directory. As I wrote above, you should provide a concrete example with the directory structure you want and we can more easily discuss such an example.

Comment: Well i dont have any specific scenario that i would want to get answered. i am just going through the basics.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain more on how to use import 'package:mypackage/somedir/somefile.dart'; for our own dart files.

Comment: I have no idea what I should add. You use this to import the file `somefile.dart` located in package `mypackage` in the subdirectory `/lib/somedir`.

Answer (score 0):

#### For absolute path

```dart
import 'package:your_app_name/lib/some_dir/some_file.dart';
```

But **skip the `lib/`**, so:

```dart
import 'package:your_app_name/some_dir/some_file.dart';
```